# Lost EU Driving licence

Tags: eu-citizens, driving-license

I lost my Romanian driving licence in the UK and it is not clear to me if I can still drive in the UK for a month until I go to Romania and replace it.

I called the Warwickshire Police and the agent wasn’t sure but guessed that I can still drive.

I would like to know for sure but I don’t seem to find a reliable reference. I called the DVLA and they don’t know neither.

Comment: 1. Are you a resident in the UK? (this is the expatriates SE so the assumption is yes, but it would be good to confirm)
2. Do you have any copy of your driving license, like a photo of both pages?

If yes on both question DVLA's form D9 might be of help

Comment: Do you mean you lost a piece of paper or plastic, or a court taking your license away? Anyway, driving with permission to drive is a serious offence. Driving without the paper or plastic evidence is much less serious.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a form D9](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1093344/d9-application-to-register-a-non-gb-driving-licence.pdf) which allows you to register (but not exchange) your foreign EU driving license. It even has option to register it if you have lost it, although there are no real information on what this exactly means and what to send them if this happens.

It would also be good to know if you have any copy of your current license, including a photograph of both sides of it. Contrary to some other countries in the UK it is not necessary to have your license with you while driving and police usually accepts other proof, including a photo of it if you are stopped, but your mileage might vary - I did once had to show them a copy on my phone and they were okay with it, although it was around 10 years ago in London and was a routine check and not because I made an offence.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, in the UK you are not required to have your drivers licence with you while driving, **but** must present it within a reasonable period upon demand by the police.

At present you cannot do this.

If you are no longer a resident of Romania, why do you think that they will replace the lost drivers licence?

Within the EU you are not required to 'convert/exchange' your existing licence when moving to another EU country, but a renewal or replacement must be done in your country of residence.

Comment: Nothing in the question says anything about residence, the caveat is potentially relevant but the tone is totally uncalled for. The answer also fails to fully address the question or to provide any details on the options the OP would have in the UK if they cannot get a replacement. If you want to go there even though that's not what the question is about, you would need to address that instead of commenting on what would happen in the EU (e.g. do you need to pass the exam again? Does the EU withdrawal agreement have any bearing?). Currently, this feels more like a comment than anything else.